# Aligning C3 line shapes with Bar charts

Tags: c3.js

We have the following mixed line chart / bar chart in C3:

- a bar chart with two groups (light/dark blue is one group, gray is the 
  other group)
- two other data sets represented as line with stroke-width = 0 that represent the limit for group1 and group2.

How can we place the circle shape for line1 aligned with the bar for group1 and the circle shape for line2 aligned with the two bars of group2?

In the following example, we basically would want one of the two circles to be moved slightly to the right so to align with the center of a group and the other one slightly to the left.

```js
var chartSettings = {
        padding: {
            left: 120,
            right: 120
        },
        bindto: '#chart',
        data: {
            x: 'Dates',
            type: 'bar',
            types: {
                line1: 'line',
                line2: 'line'
            },
            groups: [
                ['data2', 'data3'],
            ],
            colors: {
                data1: '#f3e274',
                data2: '#85bdde',
                data3: '#ccebfb'
            },
        },
        bar: {
            width: {
                ratio: 0.50 
            }
        },
        point: {
            r: 8
        },

        axis: {
            x: {
                type: 'timeseries',
                tick: {
                    format: '%d-%m-%Y'
                }
            },
            y: {
                label: { // ADD
                    text: '',
                    position: 'outer-middle'
                },
     
            },
        }
  };
  
  var date1 = new Date(2015, 1, 1, 0,0, 0,0);
  var date2 = new Date(2015, 3, 1, 0,0, 0,0);
  var date3 = new Date(2015, 6, 1, 0,0, 0,0);
  var xAxis = ['Dates', date1, date2,date3];
  var line1 = ['line1', 50, 60,55];
  var line2 = ['line2', 70, 75,60];
  var data1 = ['data1', 40, 35,30];
  var data2 = ['data2', 5, 10,10];
  var data3 = ['data3', 20, 15,30];
  chartSettings.data.columns = [xAxis,
            line1,
            line2,
            data1,
            data2,
            data3];
 c3.generate(chartSettings);
```

```css
#cr-chart .c3-line-accordatoTotale {
    stroke-width: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.11/c3.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart"/>
```

```js
var  chartSettings = {
        bindto: '#chart',
        data: {
            x: 'Dates',
            type: 'bar',
            types: {
                line1: 'line',
                line2: 'line'
            },
            groups: [
                ['data2', 'data3'],
            ],
            names: {
                line1: 'Limit for data1',
                line2: 'Limit for data2 + data3',
                data1: 'Data1',
                data2: 'Data2',
                data3: 'Data3'
            },

        },
        bar: {
            width: {
                ratio: 0.50 // this makes bar width 50% of length between ticks
            }
        },
        point: {
            r: 8
        },

        axis: {
            x: {
                type: 'timeseries',
                tick: {
                    format: '%d-%m-%Y'
                }
            },
            y: {
                label: { // ADD
                    text: '',
                    position: 'outer-middle'
                }
            },
        }
    };

var date1 = new Date(2016, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
var date2 = new Date(2016, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
var date3 = new Date(2016, 6, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
var xAxis = ['Dates',date1,date2,date3];
var line1 = ['line1', 50, 70,80];
var data1 = ['data1', 30, 40, 60];
var line2 = ['line2', 70, 60,40];
var data2 = ['data2',10,15,20];
var data3 = ['data3',15,30,5];
chartSettings.data.columns = [xAxis,
            line1,
            line2,
            data1,
            data2,
            data3];
c3.generate(chartSettings);
```

```css
 
#chart .c3-line-line1 {
    stroke-width: 0px;
}

#chart .c3-line-line2 {
    stroke-width: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.11/c3.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice if you attached some jsfiddle.
But at this point I can say that you probably need to look inside **.c3-chart-lines** container and find desired line eighter **by order**:

```
.c3-chart-line:first-child  // or last-child?
```

or **by data name**:

```
.c3-chart-line.c3-target-YOUR-ORANGE-DATA-NAME
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: And then I need to apply a margin?

Comment: No, margin will not work for svg contents. You need transform: translateX(...);

Comment: I've added the jsfiddle as you suggested

Comment: transform only works but we need that to be dynamic or page-resizing won't work

Comment: In that case you can dynamically calculate and apply transform in c3js onrendered() callback - it will be called after page resize too. Use d3.select(...).style('transform", '...').

Comment: can you provide some links and examples?